# 403 Error while trying to export a DB into a Storage Account in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I am using PowerShell to export a DB using the command `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport`.

My command looks something like

```
$name = 'admin'
$my_password = 'password'
$db = 'my-db'
$server = 'my-db-sqlserver'
$sa_key = 'storage_account_key' 
$sa_uri = 'https://testingimmutableblob.blob.core.windows.net/testdbimmutable/test_export.bacpac' 


New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName 'my_resource' -ServerName $server -DatabaseName $db -StorageKeyType 'StorageAccessKey' -StorageKey $sa_key -StorageUri $sa_uri -AdministratorLogin $name -AdministratorLoginPassword $my_password
```

When I run the last command I get the error

```
Unexpected exception encountered while retrieving metadata for blob
```

I am not sure what the issue is. I have searched around and found that sometimes the time on the server can be mismatched. I checked and the time on the server seems to be correct. I also went into the DB and tried to export it by using the interface. I got the exact same error which is interesting.

Any ideas?

```
Inner exception Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException:The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.; Inner exception System.Net.WebException:The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

Comment: Just wondering if your storage account is behind a firewall? Please check the firewall rules for the storage account in Azure Portal.

Comment: Could you please tell me if you can do that via Azure Portal?

Comment: Besides, please add `-debug` to your PowerShell command to get the detailed error message.

Comment: I get the same error when trying to export via the portal interface. I believe it has to do with firewall issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your Storage Firewalls and virtual networks, set  `Allow access from All networks`:
[image]

Or add your client IP to the network firewall:
[image]

If you only set `Allow read access to storage logging from any network`:
[image]

You will get the 403 error when access the storage:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

403 means forbidden. It is most probably related to permissions. Please regenerate the key. Are you using a user account that is not the SQL Server admin?

Another suggestion is to add the server name to the username like youremail@yourdoamin.com@dbservername.